# Connection properties along with JDBC URL for oracle thin driver

Tags: jdbc

How to supply DB connection properties along with JDBC URL when we used Oracle thin driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a [very good documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) on that point.

It boils down to:

Create a `Properties` file, add the connection properties you need and add them into your call to

```
 getConnection(String URL, Properties info);
```

Given your comment, you could *try* the following - but I could find no documentation that this connection property is **actually available on the thin driver**. [This document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jdbc_drivers/oracle.html) that points to that driver suggests it's part of the deprecated weblogic oracle driver.

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 p.setProperty ("user", youruser);
 p.setProperty ("password", yourpass);
 p.setProperty("EnableCancelTimeout", "true");

 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<SID>), p);
```

Comment: I want to pass the connection string properties(EnableCancelTimeout) property along with JDBC URL like this jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<SID>:EnableCancelTimeout=true.I am getting error when i used for establishing JDBC connection.